# mysql function is not working properly

Tags: mysql

My database name is  `dfeb`   and I have a table named  `invdt` and  columns named `batch_number`,`id` .I want to get the `batch_number` where id=59, using a function.But an error is showing up`function does not exist`.

```
 DELIMITER $$
CREATE
FUNCTION `dfeb`.`get_quantity`(PID)
RETURNS VARCHAR
BEGIN
DECLARE NAME_FOUND VARCHAR DEFAULT "";
SELECT `batch_number` INTO NAME_FOUND FROM `invdt` WHERE ID = PID;
RETURN NAME_FOUND
END$$

 DELIMITER ;

SELECT `get_quantity`(59) FROM `invdt`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

-- CREATE FUNCTION `dfeb`.`get_quantity`(PID)
CREATE FUNCTION `dfeb`.`get_quantity`(PID INT)
-- RETURNS VARCHAR
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
BEGIN
  -- DECLARE NAME_FOUND VARCHAR DEFAULT "";
  DECLARE NAME_FOUND VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT "";
  SELECT `batch_number` INTO NAME_FOUND FROM `invdt` WHERE ID = PID;
  -- RETURN NAME_FOUND
  RETURN NAME_FOUND;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

-- SELECT `get_quantity`(59) FROM `invdt`
SELECT `dfeb`.`get_quantity`(59) FROM `invdt`;
```

**UPDATE**

```
CREATE FUNCTION `dfeb`.`get_quantity`(PID INT)
.
.
.

-- SELECT `get_quantity`(59) FROM `invdt`
SELECT `dfeb`.`get_quantity`(59) FROM `invdt`;
```

Or

```
USE `dfeb`;

CREATE FUNCTION `get_quantity`(PID INT)
.
.
.

SELECT `get_quantity`(59) FROM `invdt`;
```

Comment: Is `dfeb` database name right, when create function it requires `schemaname`.`functionname` or `dbname`.`functionname` ?

Comment: Again `SELECT \`get_quantity\`(59) FROM \`invdt\`;` won't work as per OP's post, hope it requires schema name.